# Get data form HTTP POST request with multipart/form-data in Java (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, servlets, file-upload, httprequest

I want upload file from flash, my raw request (cached with Fiddler):

```
    POST /api/v1/exercises/uploadTableImage HTTP/1.1
    x-flash-version: 11,2,202,228
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=jdmlcuucuseqxyyyvsfjbfixukdbuesq
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Content-Length: 93737
    User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
    Host: localhost:8080
    Pragma: no-cache
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=BA009CDDBD828B931FCC3B0894FD7DCD;

    --jdmlcuucuseqxyyyvsfjbfixukdbuesq
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

    20er_1_1.jpg.jpg
    --jdmlcuucuseqxyyyvsfjbfixukdbuesq
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filedata"; filename="20er_1_1.jpg.jpg"
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream

    1


    --jdmlcuucuseqxyyyvsfjbfixukdbuesq
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"

    Submit Query
    --jdmlcuucuseqxyyyvsfjbfixukdbuesq--
```

I want save posted file

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(API_ROOT+"exercises")
public class ImageUploadingController {

    private final String imagesWebPath = "uploaded";

    @RequestMapping(value = "uploadTableImage", method = POST)
    public void uploadImage(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        // Parse the request
        FileItem uploadedFile = null;
        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if ("Filedata".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
                uploadedFile = item;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (uploadedFile != null) {
            File file = new File(request.getRealPath(imagesWebPath)+File.separator+uploadedFile.getName());
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();
            uploadedFile.write(file);

        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No files found");
        }
    }
```

But no luck, I see no items in List items = upload.parseRequest(request);. 
Due to requirements I cannot change request headers.

Comment: The line `List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);` does not compile because of `Error:(56, 52) java: incompatible types: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be converted to org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.RequestContext`. Maybe it is down to a different version of Tomcat ?

Comment: It turns out that `Tomcat` contains this package `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload` that contains the same yet slightly incopatible classes contained in the _original_ `org.apache.commons.fileupload` package. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Problem was in spring configuration xml file. From previous implementation left

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

So spring read HttpRequest before my method and

```
upload.parseRequest(request)
```

read empty stream.